# Just bought Logitech G35 headset, want to enable/disable headet in one action

Tags: usb, logitech-headset

Just bought Logitech G35 USB headset, want to enable/disable headet in one action.

I have windows 7 64 bit, and currently, to switch from the headset to my spakers (or vice versa) without unplugging the headset, i have to go thru this steps:

- right click on the sound icon
- select "sounds"
- select the "Playback" tab
- right click headset and hit enable
- right click speakers and hit disable
- same steps when wanting to switch back

I have to disable the devices, because not all of the programs which are outputting sound will switch immediately if I just set either device to default.

I am looking for this to be a single action (either a batch script or a windows shortcut to some action with parameters?)

Thanks!

Comment: Hardware solution...http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&biw=1396&bih=774&q=Audio+PC+Switcher&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=1826391348938030511&ei=BbcTTffmKYHPnAfFs7HtDQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCIQ8wIwAA#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [this](http://scubasteveva.blogspot.com/2010/12/enabling-and-disabling-usb-devices-with.html)? You could then assign a hotkey to those shortcuts.

Comment: I think the point here is the number of actions needed to switch between audio outputs, not how to disable the device altogether.

Comment: That's what his point does, just baffles me that it takes that much setup (pretty advanced users only) to do something that would seem so simple.  None the less, if that makes it easy to do, then so be it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You can record keyboard and mouse clicks into macroscripts to run.

Comment: Thanks, i've used AHK before, but I don't think i want to run it just for something so simple.   Solution would work tho.

Comment: Its worked wonders for little nit-picky things I do everyday that take more than 3 clicks of the mouse.